# Norms, Document Frequency and Suggestions in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have a field called name and I use the suggest api to get suggestions for misspellings do I need to have document frequencies or norms enabled in order to do accurate suggestions? My assumption is yes but I am curious if maybe there is a separate suggestions index in lucene that handles frequency and/or norms even if I have it disabled for the field in my main index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt if suggester can work without field length normalization, as disabling norm means you are looking for a binary value whether the term is present or not in the document field and which in turn will have impact on the similarity score of each document.

```
These three factors—term frequency, inverse document frequency, and field-length norm—are calculated and stored at index time. Together, they are used to calculate the weight of a single term in a particular document.
```

**"but I am curious if maybe there is a separate suggestions index in lucene that handles frequency and/or norms even if I have it disabled for the field in my main index."**
Any suggester will use Vector Space Model by default to calculate the cosine similarity, which in turn will use the tf-idf-norm based scoring calculated during indexing for each term to rank the suggestions, so I doubt if suggester can score documents accurately without field norm.

theory behind relevance scoring:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html#field-norm